# Non static Method referenced from stati context with superclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I have created a superclass Airplanes and a subclass Gliders

```
public class Airplanes
{
public String hasWings;
public int numberWheels;
public int numberPassengers;

    public Airplanes(String hasWings, int numberWheels, int numberPassengers)
    {
    // initialise instance variables
    this.hasWings=hasWings;
    this.numberWheels=numberWheels;
    this.numberPassengers=numberPassengers;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Gliders extends Airplanes
{
private String hasEngine;

public Gliders(String hasWings,int numberWheels,int numberPassengers,String hasEngine)
{
    super(hasWings,numberWheels,numberPassengers);
    this.hasEngine=hasEngine;
}

public void getSpec()
{
    System.out.println("Glider With wings: " + super.hasWings);
    System.out.println("Glider Wheels: " + super.numberWheels);
    System.out.println("Glider Number of passenger: " + super.numberPassengers);
    System.out.println("Glider has engine: " + hasEngine);
}
}
```

A new class test has to initialise Gliders and is written like this:

```
public class Test
{
   public Test()
   {
    Airplanes alfa = new Gliders("Yes",2,2,"Np");
    Gliders.getSpec();
   }
}
```

When i try to run Gliders.getSpec() it prints an error saying that i'm trying to reference a non static method from a static context.

I'm just wondering if what i'm trying to do is legal or not, and if it is how can i fix it?

Comment: as a side note don't do `super.hasWings` etc just use `this.hasWings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getSpec` method is non static method (instance method). So you need to create an instance of `Gliders` first.

```
new Gliders().getSpec();
```

or

```
Gliders glider = new Gliders();
glider.getSpec();
```

if you still want to call `getSpec` like that, you need to change `getSpec` to static method.

```
public static void getSpec()
{
}
```

Comment: Using the last option, i get the following error:``non static variable super can not referenced from a static context``

Comment: @BioShock `static` is not your friend, use one of the first two options

Comment: Sorry, i see your `getSpec` content and it's need access to instance variable..so you need to use the first option